# how to debug matplotlib with python3.4 that works on one windows 8 but not on another

Tags: python, windows-8, matplotlib, python-3.4

Using Python3.4 on both Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint.

I have a program that generates an interactive matplotlib graph, using the .ion() call to enable that behaviour. Other than that, it's very straightforward, in fact the entire program is below, missing only a few data related calls where noted.

It works on my work 64bit win8.1 i7x4 dell desktop. It works on my Mint17 32bit AMD home machine. It doesn't work on my new work 64bit win8.1 i3 dell laptop. When I say it doesn't work, I mean the GUI_inputs widget gets displayed (so tk and a lot besides is working), can be editted, writes debug to the console, doesn't generate any error messages, but the matplotlib graph window does not appear, and no window icon on the taskbar for it. In the absence of any system error messages, how do I find out what's missing or mis-configured?

```
import tkinter as tki
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import GUI_input_widget as iw

class App(tki.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tki.Frame.__init__(self, master=parent) # super calls do not appear to work with tk

        self.inputs = iw.GUI_inputs(self, 'inputs', execute=self.update)
        self.inputs.grid()
        self.inputs.add('gr', 'graph range', '0, 2500', iw.float_pair)
        # ... leave out a bunch of GUI_inputs stuff like the above
        # ...

        # create the graph
        plt.ion()
        self.fig = plt.figure(1)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.draw()

    def update(self):
        f = self.inputs.get()        
        self.ax.clear()

        x = f['x_data']
        y = f['y_data']
        self.ax.plot(x,y)
        self.ax.annotate('annot {}'.format(f['x_data'][0]), xy=(f['x_data'][0], 1),
                        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom')            
        # ... leave out a bazillian low level graph calls like the above
        # ...

        # and finally reshow it
        self.ax.set_xlim(f['gr'][0], f['gr'][1] )
        self.ax.set_ylim(-8, 2)
        plt.draw()            

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tki.Tk()
    root.title('fancy user title')
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```